# Is it possible to present / populate related data in predefined columns?

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012, fetchxml

How can change the presentation of the data so I get the names o the princesses by two columns, shown in "Wanted output". Column grouping on Knight's name gives me a Princess column for each of the princesses names. I only want two columns since I know that a knight will never have more than two princesses.

The the data I get from my input source is shown below as "Input data". Unfortunately I cannot use SQL to manipulate the data, since the QUERY is based on FetchXML. The only tools I can use is what I'm getting from Reporting Services (I'm using Visual Studio 2015), so have that in mind while suggesting any solutions.

Technically thers's a 1:M relation between Knight and Princess, but there's a restriction in the system so that a knight will never have more than 2 princesess. A Knight can have 0, 1 or 2 princesses.

**Input data**

```
_________________________________
|    Knight     |   Princess    |
|_______________|_______________|
|_____Adam______|_____Anna______|
|_____Adam______|____Angelica___|
|_____Erik______|_____Erika_____|
|_____Erik______|______Eva______|
```

**Output**

```
_________________________________________________________________________________
|    Knight     |   Princess 1  |   Princess 2  |   Princess 3  |   Princess 4  |
|_______________|_______________|_______________|_______________|_______________|
|_____Adam______|_____Anna______|_____Angelica__|_______________|_______________|
|_____Erik______|_______________|_______________|_____Erika_____|_____Eva_______|
```

**Wanted output**

```
_________________________________________________
|    Knight     |   Princess 1  |   Princess 2  |
|_______________|_______________|_______________|
|_____Adam______|_____Anna______|___Angelica____|
|_____Erik______|_____Erika_____|_____Eva_______|
```

**Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using choose and lookupset on the dataset:

```
=Choose(1,LookupSet(Fields!Knight.Value,Fields!Knight.Value,Fields!Princess.Value,"InputData"))
=Choose(2,LookupSet(Fields!Knight.Value,Fields!Knight.Value,Fields!Princess.Value,"InputData"))
=Choose(3,LookupSet(Fields!Knight.Value,Fields!Knight.Value,Fields!Princess.Value,"InputData"))
```

etc.

In each column.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is almost impossible, but you have lucked out by having a (quite reasonable) limit of 2 Princesses per Knight.  Any more and you would be stuck.

I would use an Table, not a Matrix object for this. First column is the Knight.

The next column has a static Header "Princess 1", with expression:

```
=Min(Fields!Princess.Value)
```

The 3rd column has a static Header "Princess 2", with expression:

```
=Iif ( Min(Fields!Princess.Value) = Max(Fields!Princess.Value) , "" , Max(Fields!Princess.Value) )
```

Comment: Just to clarify. If the Knights union, somehow in the future, managed to negotiate to be able to marry three or even four princesses, we would be out of luck?

Comment: Yes - I cant think of any method that would work for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a table with a rowgroup by Knight and within that rowgroup body add a tablix with a columngroup by Princess. Only problem would be, that the column headers Princess 1..x would have to be somehow hard coded into the underlying table.

[image: Here is how i did it]